# Navigating between tkiner windows

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, navigation, toplevel

I have a GUI application written in tkiner. I have a main welcome window that should take me to another window, and when it does I would like the welcome window to be Hidden, but still have the option to go back to the welcome window in the first window.
And this concept should continue with all other windows in the application i.e the window should be able to go back to the previsous (Hidden) window or forward to the next window while hviding the current window.
Each window is contained within a class in it's own script.

I am very confused because there doesn't seem to be any examples of this online even though it seems like a pretty basic problem. I understand that I should probably use Toplevel, I'm just confused how.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called tabs and not windows. Therefore, you should use Frame and not Toplevel in tkinter. See more at this example : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-tabbed-widget-with-python-tkinter/